# TeamCity loads custom plugin, but there's no evidence the plugin code runs

Tags: plugins, teamcity

I am playing around with a TeamCity install and developing a plugin that extends a BuildServerAdapter.  When I package it up and install it to the server, teamcity-server.log contains entries for my plugin:

- found when scanning the plugins (.BuildServer\plugins) folder
- registering agent plugin from server plugin
- loads in the shared classloader
- is loaded

The plugin is also listed on the plugins page in the server administration.

Beyond that...nothing.  I've put in various log statements, via both the logger and System.out, and I don't see them.  I've even added an exception into the constructor, and I see no evidence of that either in the system logs.  When a build happens, there's again no evidence that my code is called.

```java
public class CustomBuildServerAdapter extends BuildServerAdapter {

    private SBuildServer myBuildServer;
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(CustomBuildServerAdapter.class);

    private void debug(String msg) { LOG.debug(msg); System.out.println(msg); }

    public CustomBuildServerAdapter(SBuildServer aBuildServer) throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("constructor is being called, at least we know that...");

        //myBuildServer = aBuildServer;
        //debug("constructor");
    }

    public void register() {
        debug("registering");
        myBuildServer.addListener(this);
        debug("registered");
    }

    public void buildFinished(SRunningBuild build) {
        debug("build finished");
        postMessage(build.getFullName() + " - " + build.getStatusDescriptor().getText());
        debug("message posted");
    }

...
```

The zip that I copy to `.BuildServer\plugins` has the following structure:

- MyTeamCityPlugin.zip

  - teamcity.plugin.xml
  - server
  - MyTeamCityPlugin.jar

    - package folders containing class files
    - META-INF

      - build-server-plugin.xml
      - MANIFEST.MF

Looking at other plugins, they use the following structure, so I've tried that as well.

- MyTeamCityPlugin.zip

  - MyTeamCityPlugin

    - teamcity.plugin.xml
    - MyTeamCityPlugin.jar

      - package folders containing class files
      - META-INF

        - build-server-plugin.xml
        - MANIFEST.MF

My build-server-plugin.xml contains the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

<beans default-autowire="constructor">
    <bean id="myplugin" class="com.blah.blah.blah.CustomBuildServerAdapter" init-method="register"/>
</beans>
```

I'm part of the way there since the teamcity-server.log does indicate it knows about the plugin, and no longer throws an exception trying to load it.  Unfortunately, not erring isn't the same working.

Using the ant build scripts from the sample plugin, I get the following error, so I've been packing things manually.  This results in the seemingly successful load per above.

> Failed to initialize spring context for plugin MyTeamCityPlugin.  Error creating bean with name 'simpleRunnerRunType':  instantiation of bean failed.

Can anyone give me the kick I need to get this running correctly?

Comment: If your plugin is listed on Plugins page (Administration -> Server Configuration), then your class was loaded and initialized. How did you check the plugin is working? By looking at server log? But in this case you need to log with info or warn priority, because debug is disabled by default.

Comment: In case stdout/err is redirected internally... maybe try to send an email, create some dummy files. Try to use those old fashion basic debugging techniques.

Answer (score 6):

The website describes it as being easy (yeah, if it works):

```
    1. Shut down TeamCity server.
    2. Copy the zip archive with the plugin to <TeamCity Data Directory>/plugins.
    3. Start the TeamCity server: the plugin files will be unpacked and processed automatically.
```

There is also online step-by-step guide on installing TeamCity plugin [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Installing+Additional+Plugins).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the following code:

```
Loggers.SERVER.info("Your message");
```

This will log to teamcity-server.log. Loggers class also contain other static fields like AUTH, VCS and so on. Each corresponds to separate log file (e.g. teamcity-vcs.log, teamcity-auth.log, etc.). In order to use this code you also need to add the following dependency in your **pom.xml** (for Maven):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.intellij</groupId>
  <artifactId>openapi</artifactId>
  <version>7.0.3</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This was tested with Teamcity 8.1.